# Caps under DIMM sockets?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I have DIMM sockets too close together to put caps just outside their edges.

And places they can fit are technically too far away.

Can you safely put 0402 caps in the places under the socket, where they can fit?

That'll mean between pins.

Notice each FPGA has 4 dimm sockets, 2 above and 2 below That combination is replicated 6 times on the PCB.

So it's not allowed to put the caps just above the dimms, since that becomes just below on the next replication.

They'd need to go between pins on the bottom.

Will I get grief from the board house?

I'd love to change to 0201, but we're still being told to avoid those.
[image]

Comment: "Will I get grief from the board house?" ask the board house!

Comment: "I'd love to change to 0201, but we're still being told to avoid those." Why? That sounds bad: your FPGA is a high-density BGA package, it seems. If your board house can't do 0201, they certainly won't do that overly well. Get a different board house, in that case.

Comment: I hope you've got the cooling sorted out for those DIMMs if there's no space between them. Can you fit the caps on the reverse tide of the board?

Comment: That's what I want to do.  But within the dim pins.

Comment: I have no idea about the cooling!  Worse, 10 of them stack together. It's a cube of memory!  But, I have full control over everything, and a temp sensor. I can slow it down if the temp is too high, and flash codes on those displays.

Comment: "`And places they can fit are technically too far away.`" Is that what the datasheet says? That sounds pretty absurd. They're already pretty far away from the FPGA.

Comment: So you're a VHDL guy???  Me too.
It was all downhill after Assembly language. With VHDL, you have infinite power!

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Actually the last time I asked them was 10 years ago.  I suspet I'll switch then, since they don't make new guys uncomfortable.  I've been at this 40 years. When I started, surface mount was considered impossible to do by hand (and they were 0603 min!).